# Trying to add route, getting "Couldn't find Comfy::Cms::Page" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comfortable-mexican-sofa

Hell SO,

I've just started a new project with ComfyMexicanSofa being used as the CMS. I'm running into an issue where I try to add a new route to routes.rb. Here is an example of the last two lines in routes.rb, I believe the first one is the issue, and the second is the route that isn't working:

```
comfy_route :cms, :path => '/', :sitemap => false
post '/facebook_login', to: 'callbacks#login'
```

When I try to post to http://localhost:3000/facebook_login I get an 404 not found error. I also tried switching that route to get and visited the page, and received the "Couldn't find Comfy::Cms::Page" error.

From what I understand, the comfy_route line makes it so anything after '/' will look in the cms for content. I was under the impression that anything specified after that line would take precedence. I'm obviously incorrect...

Do any of you have any ideas how I can still set routes while using ComfyMexicanSofa? I've been able to find any other mention in searches referring to this issue. I'm very new to Rails, so I apologize if I'm doing something really stupid...

Thanks for your time!
-Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the cms docs:

> Make sure that content serving route appears as a very last item

So do this:

```
post '/facebook_login', to: 'callbacks#login'
comfy_route :cms, :path => '/', :sitemap => false
```

Comment: Well... I'm stupid. So I was originally working with that code the way you have it, but I had it using a controller that was within the Devise scope. So I was receiving a totally different error before and didn't realize it. I switched it back to the way you had it there, and then created a new controller that wasn't utilized by Devise, and it worked. Derp. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: It's a globbing route. If you put it before other routes they will get eaten.